# Keycloak Spring boot configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to configure Spring Boot and Keycloak for SSO.
I've created a basic AngularJS application that do some requests to the Spring boot backend.
[using this](http://slackspace.de/articles/authentication-with-spring-boot-angularjs-and-keycloak/)

The Angular app is working fine and now I'm trying to follow the new Spring Boot Keycloak apdater docuementation [here](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/securing-client-applications-guide/content/topics/oidc/java/spring-boot-adapter.html)

This is my keycloak.json that is in the WEB-INF folder.

```
{
  "realm": "my-backend",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "realm-public-key": "MIIB...",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "my-backend",
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "a75f55ca-8174-4072-8c60-b545c9ebf7e1"
}
```

Here is my security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1*").hasRole("user")
                .antMatchers("/admin/hello*").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

The 2 roles, 'admin' and 'user' are created in Keycloak and the current user has this roles.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class PharmaController {

    public class Response{
        private String message;

        public Response(String msg){
            this.message = msg;
        }
        /**
         * @return the message
         */
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        /**
         * @param message the message to set
         */
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(
            path="api/v1/userinfo", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void getUserInformation(KeycloakAuthenticationToken token) {
        if(token != null){
            System.out.println("token :" + token);

            try {
                System.out.println(token.getAccount().getPrincipal().getName());
                System.out.println(token.getAccount().getRoles());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } 

        }else{
            System.out.println("User not connected.");
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            path="admin/hello", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response adminHello(KeycloakAuthenticationToken token) {
        return new Response("Hello");
    }

}
```

1. Even if the user doesn't have any of this role, he can access **api/v1/userinfo** with this response

```js
{"data":"","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8080/api/v1/userinfo","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Authorization":"BEARER eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJSN2JSQUgtcmUwNnVEMHh4Vlotd1dyWVIycVI0S0pyMDFIZWQ2QmJMNnA4In0.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.M1RvECaBV3jvNXRxQzLzS4bfKnK-gQp85mkr9GD8HbOsGRui81pZP3Pb_NJ-ieaQ7pca7tO_06UNeSqbHut7c1APV3_GEGTnwuCkKdbu1QKrVwXSXMWNyt0nu_MOdjhzG3bQat3aG68b744KdCSi5i8OBg2L4I3Zmc6nPX5vklf1U7LUXyvs_bswLPZEy1_VQ_ACu_BSIVA8iv64Nl4ng4QlEc6pyEHbhQ2pKpE7wNIiZe-ndfeQWU5FgnV0Ya16b2Up9ZnFw7fpGHDGjzlIEV_As3K32vON171OuAhTKmIbVnG4kuoijQzeqHmkoB-ldfMKPPlLheSILtHvRn8WkA"}},"statusText":""}
```

2. The endpoint **admin/hello** is not reachable.

This is the stack trace :

```
[org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@63858877:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4d4fa76c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51832]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.739 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /admin/hello HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    Connection: keep-alive
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Origin: http://localhost:9000
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
    Authorization: BEARER eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJSN2JSQUgtcmUwNnVEMHh4Vlotd1dyWVIycVI0S0pyMDFIZWQ2QmJMNnA4In0.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.S5Jhrea_JzlXEuMPSfJ9Sd8HdNQyknklfdZFDMH_vaFWHiQShVVQAhM3wbwrz8NoJs3M6iFnkA-kuMPhCUR52y65HJ9mEXSxrUN6hPY4U9mEYIKw_kGVXFf_xOirA8lO9cvEmw7c7p2BN0DWmi85RshqhM6CEdGAtIL4z-rl-b3UDJkm9dT3uaMxcYb3l8lq0AkixqnaI8seFLdLgacdhfMblnKuyP6bgWUD2jl2X9ruVGfIHQeBdA19WesMJKHm9XqQaF1mjl0AM0k52bU7GZZ6cOD3yFwl2RMAUMlUPPyX9xq2L5kNEsgYdw4qlgdvjLaX_HipqHh7JHQksJv4Sg
    Referer: http://localhost:9000/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4

    ]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.740 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /admin/hello
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.740 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.740 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.740 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.740 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2683da6f
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.740 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /admin/hello' doesn't match 'OPTIONS /**
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.741 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.741 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.742 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.742 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.743 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.743 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8080/admin/hello
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /admin/hello' doesn't match 'POST /sso/logout
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/admin/hello'; against '/sso/login'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.744 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.871 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] a.s.a.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator : Completing bearer authentication. Bearer roles: [uma_authorization] 
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.871 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User 'user1' invoking 'http://localhost:8080/admin/hello' on client 'pharma-backend'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.871 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer AUTHENTICATED
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.871 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: AUTHENTICATED
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.871 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.872 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.889 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.k.a.s.management.HttpSessionManager    : Session created: D309F84825BE807C7B34F16B111E92CD
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.890 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl   : Registering session D309F84825BE807C7B34F16B111E92CD, for principal user1
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.891 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success using bearer token/basic authentication. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@a08a84cd: Principal: user1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@4ebe3c30; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='uma_authorization'}
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.891 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.891 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.891 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@a08a84cd: Principal: user1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@4ebe3c30; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='uma_authorization'}'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy@29a23c3d
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl   : Registering session D309F84825BE807C7B34F16B111E92CD, for principal user1
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl   : Removing session D309F84825BE807C7B34F16B111E92CD from principal's set of registered sessions
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl   : Removing principal user1 from registry
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@20f0cc02
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@a08a84cd: Authentication: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@a08a84cd: Principal: user1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@4ebe3c30; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='uma_authorization'}' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1a43aa14
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.892 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin/hello at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.893 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /admin/hello' doesn't match 'POST /sso/logout
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.893 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/admin/hello'; against '/api/v1*'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.893 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/admin/hello'; against '/admin/hello*'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.893 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/hello; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_admin')]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.893 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@a08a84cd: Principal: user1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@4ebe3c30; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='uma_authorization'}
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.895 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@58311096, returned: -1
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.896 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.899 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

    org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
  ...
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]

    2017-01-09 07:11:46.899 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5ca0c4c5
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.899 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@a08a84cd: Authentication: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@a08a84cd: Principal: user1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@4ebe3c30; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='uma_authorization'}' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1a43aa14
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.899 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.899 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2683da6f
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.900 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.901 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.902 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.904 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.904 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.904 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.927 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Mon Jan 09 07:11:46 MYT 2017, status=403, error=Forbidden, message=Access is denied, path=/admin/hello}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@45db4b8b]
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.927 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.927 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.928 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for futher output
    2017-01-09 07:11:46.928 DEBUG 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@63858877:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4d4fa76c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51832]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
```

Comment: For the user info, try switching from `"/api/v1*"` to `"/api/v1/**"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went through the same and here are my findings.

org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter assumes that your roles start from

```
private String rolePrefix = "ROLE_";
```

There is no such assumption in Keycloak (unless you name all your roles ROLE_someName), therefore no roles are actually found matching.

Similar explanation can be obtained from Spring Security Javadoc of SecurityExpressionOperations class for hasRole method

```
This is similar to {@link #hasAuthority(String)} except that this method implies
that the String passed in is a role. For example, if "USER" is passed in the
implementation may convert it to use "ROLE_USER" instead. The way in which the role
is converted may depend on the implementation settings.
```

To sum it up, I've ended with exactly the same solution as you did, using hasAuthority instead of hasRole now.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it myself by replacing hasRole() by hasAuthority().
I still don't know why keycloak role is mapped to spring security authority. Any explaination is welcomed. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## 2022 updates

Keycloak spring adapters [are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). **Do not use it**.

Instead, use directly `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` or better libs from [this repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons). Here after, the configuration for both solutions (with a thin wrapper I wrote to enable resource-server configuration from properties file, and "pure Spring" which is quite more verbose).

### Resource-server security with the two options

#### requirements

- Spring Boot 2.7 and later: without the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
- User authorities from `realm_access.roles`, `resource-access.spring-addons-confidential.roles` and `resource-access.spring-addons-public.roles`
- `401` HTTP status if authentication is missing/invalid and `403` if access is denied
- CORS: required for "pure" resource servers; UI components being served from another socket, host, or domain; cross-origin is necessary
- "Stateless" session management: no servlet session; client state is managed with URIs and access token
- disabled CSRF protection if sessions are disabled (but enabled CSRF if session management is not set to stateless)
- OpenAPI spec (from spring-doc-openapi) as well as readiness and liveness probes should accessible to anonymous
- All other routes restricted to authenticated users
- Force HTTPS usage if SSL is enabled

#### spring-addons

All of above is done in 2 very simple steps:

- choose one of the 4 starters (depends you're configuring servlet / reactive and JWT-decoder / introspection resource-server): `spring-addons-{webmvc|webflux}-{jwt|introspecting}-resource-server`
- define a few properties:

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-public.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-confidential.roles
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/greet/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/actuator/health/readiness,/actuator/health/liveness,/v3/api-docs/**
```

And this is all of java conf you need (every thing else is [auto-configured with components you can override](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/#custom)):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig {
}
```

#### `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`

You'll have to write by yourself all that was auto-configured above, including authorities mapping from **all** private claims Keycloak puts it into. This is quite some Java conf. Acceptable if you maintain few applications, less in micro-services scenarios:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    public interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        // This is a converter for roles as embedded in the JWT by a Keycloak server
        // Roles are taken from both realm_access.roles & resource_access.{client}.roles
        return jwt -> {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
            // We assume here you have "spring-addons-confidential" and "spring-addons-public" clients configured with "client roles" mapper in Keycloak
            final var confidentialClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("spring-addons-confidential", Map.of());
            final var confidentialClientRoles = (Collection<String>) confidentialClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
            final var publicClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("spring-addons-public", Map.of());
            final var publicClientRoles = (Collection<String>) publicClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            return Stream.concat(realmRoles.stream(), Stream.concat(confidentialClientRoles.stream(), publicClientRoles.stream()))
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    }

    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter, ServerProperties serverProperties)
            throws Exception {

        // Enable OAuth2 with custom authorities mapping
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        // Enable anonymous
        http.anonymous();

        // Enable and configure CORS
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Enable CSRF with cookie repo because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository());

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 403 (redirect to login) when authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        });

        // If SSL enabled, disable http (https only)
        if (serverProperties.getSsl() != null && serverProperties.getSsl().isEnabled()) {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        } else {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
        }

        // Route security: authenticated to all routes but actuator and Swagger-UI
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health/readiness", "/actuator/health/liveness", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        // Very permissive CORS config...
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        // Limited to API routes (neither actuator nor Swagger-UI)
        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/greet/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

### PS

The difference between Spring roles vs authorities mentionned in other answers still applies: for Spring, roles are just authorities with the `ROLE_` prefix. This means that `hasRole("USER")` is strictly equivalent to `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")`.

If you want to use `hasRole` and not `hasAuthority`, You'll have to choose between one of the following:

- prefix all roles with `ROLE_` in Keycloak
- configure authorities mapper in Spring to add `ROLE_` prefix (there is a property for that in `spring-addons` lib referenced above)

Comment: You should disclose that you are (obviously) the author of the referenced lib. Aside from that, I think it is no security improvement from migrating from an official Keycloak adapter to an unknown library with no huge community behind it.

Comment: You should have look at source code before writing such assumptions (it is open-source and each starter is composed of three files only). As mentioned in Readme, this libs are nothing more than thin wrappers around spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server which is quite "official". Talking about security, just compare transitive dependencies versions and consider that Keycloak adapters are deprecated (see "official" announcement linked) and won't even work with spring-boot 3 (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter does not exist anymore)

Comment: And also, note that the my answer exposes the configuration using only spring "official" libs (without anything from "my" libs). I put both to show what is auto-configured by "my" starters and demo why it is valuable (just count code lines).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement SimpleAuthorityMapper() :

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
  SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
  mapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
  return mapper;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper( grantedAuthoritiesMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

configureGlobal: Here we change the Granted Authority Mapper. By default in Spring Security, roles are prefixed with ROLE_. We could change that in our Realm configuration but it could be confusing for other applications that do not know this convention, so here we assign a SimpleAuthorityMapper that will make sure no prefix is added.

Click [here](https://dzone.com/articles/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-k)!

> ROLE_ is the prefix default for sring security roles.